# NServiceBus messaging across private networks

Tags: networking, architecture, nservicebus, lan

I was assigned with the re-architecture of a legacy (medical) product which is controlling several external devices. In the current architecture, we have several such stations in each customer's network, where each station is processing its own data, and they all share some of that data via a central server (that talks to the DB and BLOB storage).

I'm planning the new architecture such that it will allow more scenarios, such as monitoring the stations through a web interface, and allowing data processing to be scalable by adding additional servers.

This led me to choose NServicebus as the messaging and communication infrastructure. And I pretty much have a clear view of the new architecture.

However, another factor was recently added to the equation by my manager. He requires that the machine that communicates with the devices (hardware), will not be under the IT policies of the customer. The reason behind this, as I understand, is that we don't want the customer's IT to control OS updates, security, permissions and other settings, because we want full control over that machine in order to work properly with our hardware.

My manager thus added a requirement that this machine will be disconnected from the customer's LAN.

If I still want to deploy NServiceBus on that separated machine (because I want to pub/sub async messages to other machines - some are on the customer's LAN and some aren't), Will it require some special deployment? Will it require an NServiceBus gateway?

EDIT: I removed the other (1st) question, as it wasn't relevant to the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding question 2, yes it would require the use of a "Gateway", however the current [NServiceBus Gateway implementation](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/introduction-to-the-gateway) does not support pub/sub so you would have to look at alternatives.